# Windows 7 WOL - weird boot

Tags: wake-on-lan

hi i am trying to set up WOL.

My computer does receive a magic packet and it is trying to boot up. but instead of booting up normally into windows i get a weird POST boot screen like something is wrong. (See picture) after this boot screen it goes into loading screen of windows.

When it is done i get a black screen and nothing happens. No cursor aswell.

Notice the black strokes in the picture.

Step 1 after WOL sent
[image]

After that a screen comes with Loading operating system. This screen also contains black strokes

After This black screen with nothing on it. Computer is also not accessible in the network from windows explorer. No services started. Nothing

Normally computer boots like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings. WOL can be configured to boot a separate utility or rescue partition instead of the normal boot partition. If you don't have the other partition or it's not bootable, it won't work, including possible scrambled display.

Comment: Can you tell me to look along which way?

Comment: Um, look at all of the settings to do with Wake On LAN?

Comment: I guess it is under Power Management? But it does not really say something like Wake on LAN. only ACPI Suspend Type, Soft Off by Power Button, USB Wake up from s3, modem ring resume, PME Event Wake up, HPEI Support, AC Back function, Erp Support